# How to Hide the 'Open' Banner on safari browser for universal linking

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

I am using the universal linking and all is working fine. For my website there is an open banner are showing, if mobile app has installed in my device. I want to hide these banner for particular pages. Currently these banner are showing on all pages. I want to hide it for all other pages except to home page.

[image]